# how can i show chart with my database values

Tags: javascript, php, graph, charts

i am using graph from http://www.chartjs.org this is an JavaScript ,but I want to display the data on the chart from my database value. can any one guide me how to do it

Comment: Get Data before graph loads. You can use PHP variables in JavaScript also. Give me your code so that I can help you.

Comment: can you tell me how to use php variable in javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
$query = "select * from table";
$res = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
```

Define the above code before Graph content loads. And then use it in JavaScript.

```
<script>

var value1 = <?php echo $row['field1']; ?>
var value2 = <?php echo $row['field2']; ?>

</script>
```

You can use like this. Tell me do have any further query.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, i didn't try it but i am going to let it now let you know when i have issue

Comment: Sure. Let me know if you want any further help.

Comment: Hi thanks once again its possible to write php code in the js page

Comment: sorry my comment is not clear can you tell me how to write the php code inside the javascript page

Comment: As I told you in my answer, Define global variables, assign values from PHP code & then define JavaScript file. Inside JavaScript file use global variables.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54697/discussion-between-xavi-and-anand-solanki).

Comment: Have you get solution ?